# Cant get simple if loop to work with $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a image-slider that slides a div with a new image in and sets the css attributes of the new div to display:block; and z-index:5;. It also sets the divs with the images that are not visible to display:none; and z-index:0;

I now want to add a class only to the current image-div that meets the condition z-index:5;

I have tried the following code but $(this) is not working and i dont have a clue how to only add a class that currently meets the condition.

```js
if ($(".slides_control").children().css( "z-index", "5" )){
 $(this).addClass("test");
} else{
 $(this).removeClass("test");
}
```

```html
<div class="slides_control">
Container div
   <div>div with the first image</div>
   <div>div with the second image</div>
   <div>div with the second image</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(".slides_control").children().css( "z-index", "5" )` is setting the zindex not checking it. you want `$(".slides_control").children().css( "z-index" ) == "5"` (as a side note, you should know what type you return and not use ==. use === instead. read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)

Answer (score 2):

You can just do this

```
var arr = $(".slides_control").children().filter(function() {
    return $(this).css("z-index") == "5"
}).addClass('test');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesnt seem to work. The classes didnt get added to the element. Thanks for showing me .filter(), wasnt aware of it.

Comment: @thegrandwizard check now.

Comment: @thegrandwizard I don't know what you're "doesn't work" mean. Prepare a fiddle